# (EXCEL) How to make a final column that counts the number of numbers that is larger compared to the other row in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to make a table that, in its final column, counts the number of numbers such that the row is larger than the other row. However, since the sample size for me is rather large, I want an excel formula to do this for me.

I have tried using `sum`, `if`, `sumif`, `sumifs` commands, but none seems to work (at least I can't get it to work). Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a small sample:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `=SUM(--(row_2_range>row_1_range))`.

For example:

[image]

EDIT: to account for blanks and non-numeric data, you can use something like

`=SUM(--(IF(ISNUMBER(G3:I3),G3:I3,0)>IF(ISNUMBER(G2:I2), G2:I2,0)))`

Comment: Does it matter if I might have blank cells in between? (that is, blank cells for both rows) Also, what is the difference of `sum` and `sumproduct` proposed in the other answer? (since they both work in this situation)

Comment: @CELLSecret if they are truly blank, it should not matter. But if the blanks are the result of a formula (i.e. the value is something like ""), you can use the edit I made above. I'm ignorant to the utility (if any) of ```SUMPRODUCT``` as opposed to ```SUM``` for this issue

Answer (score 1):

You may try `SUMPRODUCT()`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:F1>A2:F2))
```

In `G2` cell `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:F2>A1:F1))`.

[image]

Comment: Does it matter if I might have blank cells in between? (that is, blank cells for both rows)
Also, what is the difference of `sumproduct` and regular `sum` proposed in the other answer? (since they both work in this situation)